# What is a better way to get filenames of downloaded mods from nexusmods download history?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox

I have downloaded many mods from NexusMods, currently my download history tells me that I have downloaded 150 different mods. Because I have downloaded so many mods I literally have no idea which file is from which mod for which game...

If you have used NexusMods, you know its download history tab only shows you the name of the mod you have downloaded (and the hyperlink to it), it doesn't tell you the actual filename of the file you have downloaded, requiring you go to the mod page to figure it out.

In the file tab of the mod page a list of descriptive names for the files available for downloading is displayed, but they are not the actual filenames of the files that you can download, you have to click <kbd>Manual Download</kbd> to actually see the real filenames.

There aren't necessarily any clear relationships among game name, mod name, descriptive name and actual filenames, often there aren't, and it can be extremely hard to know which file is for which mod for which game from filename alone, sometimes I can use Google to find out which file is for which mod for which game, but often Google doesn't help.

I tried Google searching for a way to resolve downloaded filename to mod name, and found nothing relevant which is totally not surprising. So I decided to post a question here, and, because I am supposed to show my research effort but I have no idea how much is enough, I spent the last few hours writing a completely working but very inefficient solution just to show my research effort.

I used Python + Selenium + Firefox in this, the basic idea is to get the links to the downloaded mods from the download history, then visit every single mod page in a web browser, and click <kbd>Manual Download</kbd> to see the actual filenames. You can see all the steps in all their glorious details in my code below.

You will need this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt-locally/cclelndahbckbenkjhflpdbgdldlbecc/related) and obviously a NexusMods account to test my script, you have to go to https://www.nexusmods.com in Chrome, login your account, and use the extension linked above to export the cookies to a .json file, then change the file path in my script to point to that file to login your account in selenium. Because you can't sign in using https://users.nexusmods.com/auth/sign_in in selenium, believe me, I tried.

Then you may also want to use Firefox developer tools Network tab to check which advertisement services, trackers, injectors and whatnot are loaded when loading the website, this is optional, but disabling them can speed up the execution of the script massively.

I went to https://www.nexusmods.com and exported the requests to a .json file (save all as HAR), I then went to https://www.nexusmods.com/users/myaccount?tab=download+history and exported the requests to another .json file, and finally I went to a mod page to export the requests to yet another .json file, I then got all the unique domain names from all three files using the following:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

domains = {e['request']['url'].replace('https://', '').split('/')[0] for e in json.loads(Path('D:/data.json').read_text(encoding='utf8'))['log']['entries']}
domains |= {e['request']['url'].replace('https://', '').split('/')[0] for e in json.loads(Path('D:/data1.json').read_text(encoding='utf8'))['log']['entries']}
domains |= {e['request']['url'].replace('https://', '').split('/')[0] for e in json.loads(Path('D:/data2.json').read_text(encoding='utf8'))['log']['entries']}
print('\n'.join(sorted(domains)))
```

And I found 150 bad websites and updated %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts accordingly, [the changes made](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aP3beRPqCLqypWg8kOomYNK5qdWm_dt6/view?usp=share_link)

And this is my script:

```py
import json
import time
from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 1)
options.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
options.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
options.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')
options.set_capability('pageLoadStrategy', 'eager')

Firefox = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(Firefox, 3)

def scrape_files(mod_url):
    result = {
        'url': mod_url,
        'files': dict()
    }
    Firefox.get(mod_url+'?tab=files')
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//dt[contains(@id, "file-expander-header")]')))
    filelinks = dict()
    for i, e in enumerate(Firefox.find_elements(by='xpath', value='//dt[contains(@id, "file-expander-header")]')):
        try:
            e.find_element(by='xpath', value='./div/i')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
        name = e.get_attribute('data-name')
        try:
            link = Firefox.find_element('xpath', f'(//dd[@class="clearfix open"])[{i+1}]//a[contains(@class, "btn inline-flex")]').get_attribute('href').replace('&nmm=1', '')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            Firefox.find_element(by='xpath', value=f'(//div[@class="acc-status"])[{i+1}]').click()
            link = Firefox.find_elements('xpath', '//dd[@class="clearfix open"]//a[contains(@class, "btn inline-flex")]')[-1].get_attribute('href').replace('&nmm=1', '')
        finally:
            filelinks[name] = link
    
    for name, link in filelinks.items():
        requirements = None
        Firefox.get(link)
        if 'ModRequirementsPopUp' in link:
            required = {e.find_element(by='xpath', value='./span').text: e.get_attribute('href') for e in Firefox.find_elements(by='xpath', value='//div[@class="mod-requirements-tab-content"]/ul/li/a')}
            modlink = Firefox.find_element('xpath', '//div[@class="mod-requirements-tab-content"]/a[@class="btn"]').get_attribute('href')
            if required:
                requirements = {k: scrape_files(v) for k, v in required.items() if v.startswith('https://www.nexusmods.com/')}
                if not requirements:
                    requirements = None
            Firefox.get(modlink)
        file = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="header"]'))).text.splitlines()[0]
        result['files'][name] = {'requirements': requirements, 'filename': file}
    
    return result

Firefox.get('https://www.nexusmods.com/')
for i in json.loads(Path('D:/cookies.json').read_text()):
    Firefox.add_cookie({'name': i['name'], 'value': i['value']})

Firefox.get('https://www.nexusmods.com/users/myaccount?tab=download+history')
time.sleep(10)

mods = dict()
while True:
    for mod in Firefox.find_elements(by='xpath', value="//div[@class='tracking-title']/a"):
        name = mod.text
        url = mod.get_attribute('href')
        mods[name] = url
    next_button = Firefox.find_element(by='xpath', value="//div/a[contains(@class, 'paginate_button next')]")
    if next_button.get_attribute('class') != 'paginate_button next disabled':
        next_button.click()
    else:
        break

modfiles = dict()

for name, url in mods.items():
    game = url.split('/')[3]
    if not modfiles.get(game):
        modfiles[game] = {
            name: scrape_files(url)
        }
    else:
        modfiles[game][name] = scrape_files(url)

Path('D:/nexusmods_downloaded.json').write_text(json.dumps(modfiles, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4), encoding='utf8')
```

To prove to you my script is 100% working, you can see the output [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jGX_C5KenwbYBoy3kiaoaVJBvL-1aYP1/view?usp=share_link)

The task is deceptively hard, mainly because I can't use any reference to the web elements or they all will become stale, instead I have to get the links first and use the links directly. It took me several hours to complete, but I completed it all by myself without anyone's help, not even from Google.

Is there a better way to get the information like the attached output? Like maybe an API?

---

---

### Update

---

I have investigated XMLHTTPRequests and made a little progress, but I still have to pretty much rely on slow UI scraping.

I was able to find the XHR for getting download history but that's about it. I managed to get some [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18xpgVi6pI77bG2AA8VvXaT6WObULD_Tp/view?usp=share_link) using the following:

```py
import json
import requests
from pathlib import Path

cookies = json.loads(Path('D:/nexusmods_account_cookies.json').read_text())

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get(url='https://www.nexusmods.com/Core/Libs/Common/Managers/Mods?GetDownloadHistory', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
Path('D:/downloaded_nexusmods.json').write_text(json.dumps(json.loads(response.content.decode()), ensure_ascii=False, indent=4), encoding='utf8')
```

If you want to test my code you need the following values from your nexusmods cookies:

```
{
    "_app_session": "something",
    "fwroute": "something",
    "jwt_fingerprint": "something",
    "member_id": "something",
    "pass_hash": "something",
    "sid_develop": "something"
}
```

And change the file path accordingly.

I found exactly 150 entries in it, corresponding to the 150 mods I have downloaded, but I have downloaded 169 unique files, and the entries don't show the names of the files, only the file id of the latest downloaded file.

I found f'https://www.nexusmods.com/{game_name}/mods/{mod_id}?tab=files' correspond to f'https://www.nexusmods.com/Core/Libs/Common/Widgets/ModFilesTab?id={mod_id}&game_id={game_id}', but that page has UI and doesn't expose raw data... (For example: https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/57411?tab=files vs https://www.nexusmods.com/Core/Libs/Common/Widgets/ModFilesTab?id=57411&game_id=130).

And I still have to click manual download to see actual filenames, and to get to that page doesn't involve XHR at all...

So I am currently stuck, but I will keep searching.

---

### Update 2

I have managed to find this: NexusMods indeed does have an [API](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/NexusMods/nexus-mods_public_api_params_in_form_data/1.0), and you need to go to [this page](https://www.nexusmods.com/users/myaccount?tab=api+access) to get your own apikey.

I managed to get the filelist for the mods like this:

```
import json
import requests

apikey="your_api_key"

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'apikey': apikey
}

response = requests.get(url='https://api.nexusmods.com/v1/games/newvegas/mods/57411/files.json', headers=headers)
json.loads(response.content)
```

The response contains the file id, filename and descriptive name, but doesn't tell me whether I downloaded a file or not, and more importantly the mod dependencies.

And I also found out the download history I obtained via XHR doesn't contain any reference to the downloaded files at all, the first two numbers are probably timestamps and I have confirmed they aren't fileids.

Comment: First off, congrats on putting this all together by yourself with your own research and no help. You have vastly exceeded the efforts of most SO question posters. :) I wanted to help here but my nexusmods account is deactivated and I wasn't able to resurrect it. I would suggest you look into [XHR requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and see if the site uses them. If it does, you should be able to at least pull some of the data you are interested in using requests instead of UI scraping that would save you time.

Comment: The quick rampup is open the devtools in Chrome, switch to the Network tab, filter by Fetch/XHR, and then refresh the page. Click into the line items below the graph and see if there's any useful data in there. If there is, you can look up some examples of requests using XHR and go from there. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Nope, there isn't any better way to get which files I have downloaded than using XHR + RESTAPI, I guess the only efficient way to know which files are downloaded is through heuristics, first if the mod has only one file listed then it must be the file that's downloaded. If a mod has more than one file, but there is only one file marked as main, it is almost certainly the downloaded file. Finally if the above two methods fail, I can still check if any file listed is present in my downloads folder. And if all 3 methods failed to identify downloaded files, it means the mod is already installed.

Comment: But the mod dependencies are another matter, as the API doesn't expose that data at all, I guess I have to be mindful then, for now I have verified that I downloaded all dependencies properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend the last hour to write a much more efficient solution using requests, RESTAPI and XHR. Unfortunately this version doesn't guarantee to determine which files are downloaded, and completely ignores the dependency information.

But as I said, it is much more efficient than the UI based version.

The code:

```py
import json
import requests
import time
from pathlib import Path
from collections import defaultdict

cookies, headers = json.loads(Path('D:/nexusmods_identification.json').read_text()).values()

start = time.time()
history = json.loads(requests.get(url='https://www.nexusmods.com/Core/Libs/Common/Managers/Mods?GetDownloadHistory', cookies=cookies, headers=headers).content)['data']
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
history = [{'name': e[1], 'id': e[8], 'game': e[9]} for e in history]

download_history = defaultdict(list)
parsed = dict()

downloaded_files = {i.name for i in Path('D:/downloads').rglob('*')}

base_url = 'https://api.nexusmods.com/v1/games/{0}/mods/{1}/files.json'

def parse_fileitem(item):
    return {
    'file_id': item['file_id'],
    'name': item['name'],
    'category_name': item['category_name'],
    'size': item['size'],
    'file_name': item['file_name'],
    'downloaded': False
    }

def parse_entry(entry):
    name, mod_id, game = entry.values()
    if game+str(mod_id) in parsed:
        return parsed[game+str(mod_id)]
    
    response = requests.get(base_url.format(game, mod_id), headers=headers)
    filelist = json.loads(response.content)['files']
    result = {
        'name': name,
        'id': mod_id,
        'files': []
    }
    if len(filelist) == 1:
        item = parse_fileitem(filelist[0])
        item['downloaded'] = True
        result['files'].append(item)
        parsed[game+str(mod_id)] = result
        return result
    
    main_count = 0
    download_count = 0
    for item in filelist:
        item = parse_fileitem(item)
        if item['category_name'] == 'MAIN':
            main_count += 1
        
        if item['file_name'] in downloaded_files:
            item['downloaded'] = True
            download_count += 1
        
        result['files'].append(item)
    
    if not download_count and main_count == 1:
        for item in result['files']:
            if item['category_name'] == 'MAIN':
                item['downloaded'] = True
                break
    
    parsed[game+str(mod_id)] = result
    return result

start = time.time()
for e in history:
    download_history[e['game']].append(parse_entry(e))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

Path('D:/nexusmods_download_history.json').write_text(json.dumps(download_history, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4), encoding='utf8')
```

[The result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y4qv2ozFg2aVmeS4guu2NscB4OLBMU32/view?usp=share_link)

---

### Edit

Fixed a minor bug that caused the parser to copy the result for another mod of another game if the current mod in processing has the same id as the other mod.

I have also added a little profiling.

It took 1.089961290359497 seconds to list all downloaded mods, I currently have downloaded 167 mods, and the script sent 167 requests using the RESTAPI, the API calls took a combined 262.31878447532654 seconds, so the average time for the API calls is 1.5707711645229134 seconds.